# bind url to checkbox value

Tags: php, html, url, checkbox

I have this checkbox which I want to use as a language-switch:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input">
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="DE" data-off="FR"></span>
    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
</label>
```

I have one single `index.php` file where the language of the content changes to German if you add `?lang=de` or changes to french if you add `?lang=fr`. Now is it possible to bind each of the URLs to one of the checkbox value? Like if the checkbox isn't checked the param `?lang=de` and if checked, the param `?lang=fr` will be added to the URL and let show the content in this language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
var param = "lang=de";

$('.switch-input').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        param = "lang=" + $(this).siblings('.switch-label').data('on');
    } else {
        param = "lang=" + $(this).siblings('.switch-label').data('off');
    }
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '?' + param;
})
```

Comment: As you did it, the `param` variable doesn't contain the query for the url, but the url itself. The `window.location.href` should be `window.location.href = '?'+param`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I'm a little bit confused how to include this to my php file. I tried to add your code in a `<script>...</script>`and it didn't worked. And where to define the `var param = "lang=de";` ? Can someone help me?

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't imported jQuery.